# Where should i store my JSON Web Token for a 'non-singlepage' frontend application

Tags: javascript, rest, security, frontend, jwt

I've recently built a simple REST API with hapiJS using JWT as auth method. 
I now want to build a pure ES6 frontend, but it does not have to be a SPA (There will be more than just one .html file).

My Question:
What is the best way to store the JWT after login. Local Storage, Cookie ?

Comment: Depends, read this http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store it in a cookie, you'll be vulnerable to a CSRF attack, because the browser will automatically send the token with each request. See for more information on these type of attacks:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

I would recommend storing it in ***localstorage*** and then sending the token via the head of your requests. ***note***: your browser doesn't automatically do this for you!

Example:

```
x-access-token: Bearer -jwt goes here-
```

Comment: ... and that opens it up to XSS attacks because all javascript can access your localstorage.

The only way is via a httpOnly cookie.